# Python 3.2.5 on win 7 works well in command line but got error in Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7, pydev

I am working on Python 3.2.5 on win 7.

e.g.

```
  output_file = open('c:\\temp\\a_file.txt', 'w')
```

It works well on python command-line.

But, I got error "undefined variable" for "open" in Eclipse with PyDev.

The grammar syntax that I chose for pyDev in Eclipse is python 3.0.

I followed the instructions for pyDev at http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, not finding 'open' means that PyDev hasn't been able to connect to a shell to get information on the builtin modules.

This could be an active firewall preventing communication... Please check http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F and see if you can discover why with those tips (if not, please add information on the log you have in Eclipse).

p.s.: You may want to follow the steps from: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html to config PyDev in Eclipse.